# The inverse of even band matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, symmetric-matrices, sparse-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I am on my research work. I need references or if perhaps, you can help me find the modeled inverse of matrices $A(4,n), \,A(6,n),\, ...\,,\,A(2r+2,n)$ where $2r+2$ is the bandwidth. I have successfully derived the model for the inverses when $i\leq j$ which is similar to W. D. Hoskins and P. J. Ponzo's formula. Can anyone help me model when $i\geq j-1$ using LU decomposition?

Examples are

$A(4,4)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 3 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$,
$A(6,7)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 10 & -5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -10 & 10 & -5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 5 & -10 & 10 & -5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 5 & -10 & 10 & -5 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 5 & -10 & 10 & -5 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 5 & -10 & 10 & -5 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 5 & -10 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right)$,...

I have downloaded a lot of materials on banded matrix but none of them has given me a formula like "Some Properties of a Class of Band Matrices" by W. D. Hoskins and P. J. Ponzo.

Pls, I need an urgent help on this.

Comment: You should say that in $A(n,p)$, the coefficients on the $k$th line are taken in a $p$ wide sliding window on the list : $(-1)^{k+1} \binom{n}{k}$